# Groß- oder Kleinschreibung von "die gleichen"?

Tags: grammaticality

Ich schreibe gerade eine Hausarbeit und bin mir gerade unsicher.

Der Satz lautet: 
"Die Instrumente des Staates blieben die gleichen: Arbeitseinsätze, Zwangsrekrutierungen und als ultima ratio der Schub."

Schreib ich hier "die gleichen oder die Gleichen"? 
Ich würde sagen "die gleichen", weil es sich ja auf "die Instrumente" am Satzanfang bezieht oder?

Answer (score 3):

Um mal [leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idForum=4&idThread=15721&lp=ende&lang=de) zu zitieren

> Die Adjektive werden klein geschrieben, weil sie sich auf ein vorhergehendes Substantiv beziehen

Deine Vermutung ist also richtig. Es ist eine Ellipse und *die gleichen* wird in diesem Fall klein geschrieben.

Vgl. dazu den Beispielsatz des [Wikipedia-Artikels](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivierung#Syntax_und_Kenntlichkeit)

> seine Lieblingsfarbe ist **R**ot; aber: grünen Spargel mag er nicht; er isst nur **w**eißen